# Refer to the undefined value in Checking ID overlap method

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex

In code below, I'm checking Id overlap.

I want to hand over the value set to the v-model as a payload

I'm using mapState, so I handed over this.info.userid, but it doesn't work.

It keeps saying that I'm referring to the undefined value.

What value should I refer to?

this is my registration.vue

```
<div class="user-details">
  <div class="input-box">
    <span class="details">아이디</span>
    <div class="validate-box">
      <Field
        :rules="validateId"
        type="text"
        placeholder="아이디를 입력하세요"
        v-model="info.userId"
        name="userId"
        required />
      <ErrorMessage
        class="error-box"
        name="userId" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <button @click="idCheck">
        중복확인
      </button>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>

import { mapState } from 'vuex'
import { Field, Form, ErrorMessage } from 'vee-validate';
methods: {
    async idCheck() {
      this.$store.dispatch('signup/idChecking', {
        userId: this.info.userId
      })
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState('signup',{
      info: 'Userinfo'
    })
  }
```

and code below is my store registration.js

```
 state: {
    Userinfo: {
      userId: '',
      password: '',
      passwordConfirm: '',
      userName: '',
      birthDate: '',
      phoneNumber: '',
      email: '',
      year: '',
      month: '',
      day: ''
   }
},
actions: {
    async idChecking(payload) {
      const { userId } = payload
      axios.get(`http://??.???.???.???:????/api/check/${userId}`)
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
      })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I resolve the problem.
I didn't put 'state' in async idChecking method.
async idChecking(state, payload)  <- like this.